# Remove all existing objects from Aurelia Validate

Tags: aurelia

Without going into depth, I need to remove all validation objects from a Validation Controller without having access to those objects outside of the controller.  Basically this is to cleanup existing validation objects before adding new ones.  It's complex.

Very simply, I need to do this:

```
this.validationCtrl.removeAllObjects();
```

One possibility I've attempted is to inspect the validation controller and iterate through its objects property, but I'm unable to correctly access these or give the `.removeObject()` what it needs.

```
const validationObjects = this.validationCtrl.objects;
validationObjects.forEach(obj => this.validationCtrl.removeObject(obj));
```

This also doesn't work.

What is the best way to blindly remove all existing validation controller objects?

Comment: Would it be an option to use the Validation Controller Factory and to create controllers for the current scope? This way you can just nullify the property that contains the controller and start again?

Comment: It might.  I also found another way without actually re-instantiating the validation controller.  I'll post it as a solution since it's more directly an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works to delete all existing objects from the current controller:

```
  const validationEntries = Array.from(this.validationCtrl.objects);
  validationEntries.forEach(([key]) => {
    this.validationCtrl.removeObject(key);
  });
```